# Can I create a visual DSL that does not require Visual Studio?

Tags: dsl, vsx, dsl-tools

I would like to create a visual DSL (boxes and arrows). I have found that I can create such a DSL using [Microsoft's Visualization and modeling SDK](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/vsvmsdk) (DSL Tools sequel, for VS2010) and there is also a [lab](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/DSLToolsLab) on the subject. However, that would require Visual Studio 2010 to host my designer once I have created my DSL.

Is there any way to ***not*** require Visual Studio? With Windows Workflow Foundation (WF), it is possible to host a workflow designer in your own application, so it shouldn't be impossible.

Suggestions of other approaches are also welcome.

Comment: Yes, you can host the designer in a winforms app.

Comment: That's incorrect, see Aaron's correct answer, below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot host a DSL design surface in a standard Windows Forms/WPF application.

However, you can create your own application [built on top of the Visual Studio Isolated Shell](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb685691.aspx) to host your DSL. The [Storyboard Designer](http://storyboarddesigner.codeplex.com/) sample is an example of hosting a DSL in an isolated shell (although built on the VS 2008 Shell).